# Why a .term() of Jeromq blocks infinitely even I have called .close() to close all the sockets?

Tags: java, android, zeromq

I tried to use 0.4.2 of jeromq in my android app and added compile 'org.zeromq:jeromq:0.4.2' to build.gradle, but a `.connect( String addr )` in ZMQ will crash, no matter if the server program is available.

So I tried to use 0.4.0 of jeromq and `.connect()` can work, but the `.term()` of Jeromq will never return when the server program is not available.

Please see a simple version of the code below in Android and the following codes run in a thread of a Intent service.

```
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
        ZMQ.Socket client = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);                       
        client.connect("tcp://192.168.31.10:13587");           
        client.send("Android");

        final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 3000;
        ZMQ.Poller items = context.poller(1);
        items.register(client, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
        items.poll(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);          
        if (items.pollin(0)) {
           String reply = client.recvStr();
        } 

        client.close();
        context.term();
```

A call to a `client.connect( "tcp://192.168.31.10:13587" )` method will crash, if I used 0.4.2 of jeromq. If I used version 0.4.0 or 0.3.6, `context.term()` never returns, when the server program did not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are a happy man, Bob!

The why is simple - the **`.term()`-blocking is an intended behaviour** on sockets, that have a `LINGER == -1`.

just always ( yes, **ALWAYS** )
setup:

```
<aSocketInstance>.setsockopt( ZMQ.LINGER, 0 );
```

for each socket instance, right upon its instantiation, and you are done.

<sub>( there are many other API-details to fine tune, if you need to setup your app to become more robust against an error or a mis-use from an uncontrollable set of principally distributed agents, so due care is to be taken )</sub>